# linq to sql eager load self referencing property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-sql

I am trying to make a one database call to load my menu, but after researching I've noticed that there is no eager loading available for self referencing table. Right now it looks like this:

```
public ActionResult PopulateHeaderMenu()
{
 using (var context = ww.WebObjs.WebDataContext.Get())
 {
    var menus = from menu in context.MenuCaches
    where menu.URL == "MENU" && menu.ParentID == -1
    select new MenuModel
    {
        ID = menu.ID,
        Children = from x in menu.Children
                select new MenuModel
                {
                   ID = x.ID,
                   Children = from y in x.Children
                            select new MenuModel
                            {
                                ID = y.ID,
                                Children = from p in y.Children
                                    select new MenuModel
                                    {
                                      ID = p.ID,
                                      Children = from r in p.Children
                                      select new MenuModel 
                                      {
                                        ID =r.ID,
                                        Children = from s in r.Children     
                                        select new MenuModel
                                        {
                                          ID =s.ID,
                                          Children = from t in s.Children
                                             select new MenuModel
                                             {
                                               ID = t.ID,
                                             }
                                        }
                               }
                      }
                  }
            }
         };
         var model = menus.First();
         return PartialView("_NaviPartial", model);
        }

    }
```

This works rather well, but it generates 113 separate queries. I tried doing DataLoadWith(), but can't do it to self referenced property. Is there another way to do what I am trying to do here? Am I taking the wrong approach?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I did something like this several years ago (and don't have access to the code anymore). The key was to load the flat table once and then loop through the items setting a local (unmapped) property for the parent entity. With that, you can the navigate through the tree via these unmapped properties at will and only fetch the graph once. Unfortunately, you can't use the LoadWith option for self-referencing entities (see http://www.thinqlinq.com/Default/Managing-self-referencing-tables-with-LINQ-to-SQL.aspx).